# How to display in template data from model?

Tags: django

Hi I Have two models:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.ManyToManyField(Country)
```

Now I want display in template name and country every city, but when I do it:

```
{% for city in cities %}
    {{ city.name }}
    {{ city.country | linebreaks }}
{% endfor %}
```

I get this:

```
London 
city.Country.None 

Berlin 
city.Country.None 

Paris 
city.Country.None
```

What must i change?

views:

```
def city_list(request):
    cities = City.objects.all().order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'city/city_list.html', {'cities': cities})
```

EDIT:
I changed in template `city.country` on `city.country.name` but I only get this:

```
London 
None 

Berlin 
None 

Paris 
None
```

I don't know how change "none" on country name.

Second problem: i want display every city which belongs to country.

```
def England(request):
    cities = City.objects.filter(country__name__exact="England").order_by('-name')
    return render(request, 'city/city_list.html', {'cities': cities})
```

It works but I want that it will display automatically for every country, I don't want create one view to one country.

I created view which directs to country detail but how display cities which are placed in this country?

```
def country_detail(request, pk):
    country = get_object_or_404(Country, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'city/country_detail.html', {'country': country})
```

Comment: Sorry, that code wouldn't give that output.

Comment: `city.country` return many objects, not one

Comment: @znawca, now its ok?

Comment: @znawca, `city.country.all()` or in template `{{ city.country.all | linebreaks }}`

Comment: @Wolkodav it looks ok now! Maybe you know how to display in template every cities which belongs to country which I choose?

Comment: @znawca answer is very big for comments...

Comment: @znawca I edited my answer to show you how to display every cities belonging to a specific country.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your City model has a ManyToMany relation to Country Model. So in your template city.country refers to the django built in manager for related data. You need to loop over it :

```
{% for city in cities %}
    {% for country in city.country.all %}
        {{ city.name }}
        {{ country.name | linebreaks }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

In fact I think you should have a ForeignKey relation instead of ManyToMany because your Country model have many Cities but Cities only have one Country. So your final code should be the following :

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
```

and your initial template code :

```
{% for city in cities %}
     {{ city.name }}
     {{ city.country | linebreaks }}
{% endfor %}
```

EDIT :

If you want to display all cities belonging to one Country django provides a related manager, so you can use :

```
country.city_set.all()
```

Or you can use a related_name in your model for you ForeignKey such as :

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, related_name="cities")
```

So you can now use :

```
country.cities.all()
```

Comment: Thank you! About second problem i don't get it, I edited first post again and I pasted my solution which needs something else.

Comment: Do you edited your City model with a ForeignKey as shown in my example ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve in your template exactly ? Because in your country_detail template you just need to call country.city_set.all or country.cities.all if your have a related_name. You just need to loop over it :
{% for city in country.city_set.all %}{{ city.name }}{% endfor %}

Comment: Ok i had some problems, but now it works with country.cities.all, Thank you :)